# Updating a value in an ARRAY in a BigQuery table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table with a similar schema to that shown in the picture, rows that can hold arrays of structs. What syntax should I use to attempt to change/update an itemDelta.typeId to another value? (see SQL if unclear)

[BigQuerySchema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRuHO.png)

```
UPDATE itemInformation
SET    itemDelta.typeId = 9426
WHERE  itemDelta.typeId = 2424;
```

UPDATE:

One work around I found  is to implement a User-Defined-Function. BigQuery allows you to create custom functions using JavaScript.

Here is the code:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION edit(table ARRAY<STRUCT<typeId INT64, amount INT64>>)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<typeId INT64, amount INT64>>
LANGUAGE js AS """
var i;  
for(i = 0; i < table.length; i++)
{
  if(table[i].typeId == 2452)
  {
    table[i].typeId = 1000
  }
}
return table;
""";

UPDATE itemInformation
SET    itemDelta = edit(itemDelta)
where  true
```

Comment: suggestion  - don't use JS UDF if there is a way to express same logic with pure SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
UPDATE itemInformation
SET    itemDelta = ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE(9426 AS typeId) FROM UNNEST(itemDelta))
WHERE  2424 IN (SELECT typeId FROM UNNEST(itemDelta));
```

The filter isn't strictly necessary, but it may make the query slightly faster since it doesn't modify rows where `typeId` has different values in the array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This did not seem to work for me entirely. BigQuery complains with:

Error: ARRAY subquery cannot have more than one column unless using SELECT AS STRUCT to build STRUCT values

However, your query did give me an idea. BigQuery allows you to add custom js functions. I created a function that processes each rows entire itemDelta array. It makes the necessary changes and then return the new modified array.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that; I needed to use `SELECT AS STRUCT`. I updated the answer. I would suggest not using a JavaScript function if you can help it since normally you can express these kinds of transformations simply using SQL, which will be faster and cheaper (less likely to hit a higher billing tier).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 3):

```sql
#standardSQL
UPDATE `yourProject.yourTable.itemInformation`
SET itemDelta = ARRAY(
    SELECT STRUCT<typeId INT64, amount INT64>(IF(typeId = 2424, 9426, typeId), amount) 
    FROM UNNEST(itemDelta)
  ) 
WHERE 2424 IN (SELECT typeId FROM UNNEST(itemDelta))
```