# How to access column name of an array of data inside a column in a bigquery table?

Tags: sql, go, google-bigquery

I have a structure that holds an array of class objects which I uploaded to my BigQuery table using `inferschema`. However, I am now trying to iterate through that table and update the values accordingly and I am not able to access the column which holds the array of class objects.

I have already tried to access it using different class names such as:

- "Reviewers[0].Role"
- "`Reviewers[0].Role`"
- "Reviewers_0.Role"
- "Reviewers(0).Role"

... None of which works

```
//Models which I'm using for the schema of the tables
type PullRequest struct {   
Reviewers         []*Reviewer  `json:"reviewers"`
}
type Reviewer struct {
    Role   string `json:"role"`
    Status string `json:"status"`
    User   *User  `json:"user"`
}

//Putting sql statements in constant to avoid SQL injection
const (
    prUpdateSQL = "UPDATE %s.%s.%s"
    prSetSQL = "SET %v = '%v'"
    prSetNonEscapeSQL = "%v = %v"
    prSetEscapeSQL = "%v = '%v'"
    prWhereSQL = "WHERE ID = %v"
)

commandstring := fmt.Sprintf(prUpdateSQL+" ", projectID, datasetID, tableName)
for i, r := range pr.Reviewers{
                reviewerString := fmt.Sprintf("Reviewers.%d", i)
                commandstring += fmt.Sprintf(prSetEscapeSQL+", ", reviewerString+".Role", r.Role)
                commandstring += fmt.Sprintf(prSetEscapeSQL+", ", reviewerString+".Status", r.Status)
                commandstring += fmt.Sprintf(prSetEscapeSQL+", ", reviewerString+".User.Name", r.User.Name)
}
```

I am expecting the results to be able to set the different class objects values in the array to my new value which pr holds. Instead I get this error message:

> UPDATE ... SET does not support array modification with [] at [1:914], invalidQuery"

Comment: As the error message describes, DML does not support [array modifications](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_examples). You need to select the array as a [struct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301668/10161872) in order to iterate and update a value within the array.